# AndroidAnnotations, REST and custom response

Tags: rest, jackson, android-annotations

I'm using AndroidAnnotations in my project. This works fine so far...

But now I try to access a given Webservice with a custom response like this:

```
{ 
    success: true,
    total: 100,
    items: [],
}
```

This response format is the same for every GET request. The items property holds the response objects I'm interested in and the items contains different object type(like user, product etc)

I'm using "MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"...

How can I access them?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the response class, which can be deserialized from the JSON response:

```
public class CustomResponse {
  boolean success;
  int total;
  List<Integer> items;
}
```

This is just an example, because it is ambigous from your JSON snippet, what exact types you are using.
Then you can use this response class in your REST client:

```
@Get("/getsomething")
public CustomResponse getSomething();
```

It is not necessary to use `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, you could use any converter which can convert your JSON response (like a GSON converter).

Comment: First thanks for your answer :) The items property contains the objects. As I wrote, that can be a wide range... like a User, Product, Article or something else...

Comment: A heterogenous list is problematic. You can send the the type field for each item, and register a type adapter which can differentiate between the types, and deserialize them into different classes.